# sql bulk insert and df.to_sql is pointing to dbo even after giving schema

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert

I have a dataframe with 20 million rows and I want to upload it to a sql server table, It's taking hours to run, I want to finish it in minutes, I'vee tried bulk insert and df.to_sql, suggest me an efficient way

I'm trying to insert million of records to a sql server table, first I tried bulk insert but I'm facing some access error, then I tried sqlalchemy df.to_sql but even after giving schema name as 'abcXX' , it's pointing to dbo, I'm not getting that,
Sql alchemy code:

```
conn_string = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'
conn= pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://', creator= lambda: conn)
table_name = 'My_table'
schema_name = 'abcXX'
table_full = f'{schema_name}.{table_name}'
df.to_sql(name= table_full, con= engine, if_exists= 'replace', index = False)
```

code for bulk insertion:

```
csv_buffer = df.to_csv(index=False, header=False)

# Connect to the SQL Server database using pyodbc
connection_string = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server_name};DATABASE={database_name};UID={username};PWD={password}'

conn = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Prepare the BULK INSERT query
bulk_insert_query = f"BULK INSERT {table_name} FROM '{csv_buffer}' WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV', FIELDQUOTE = '\"', FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\\n', FIRSTROW = 2)"

# Execute the BULK INSERT
cursor.execute(bulk_insert_query)
conn.commit()
```

please suggest me an efficient way to do this

Comment: Two things for the `BULK INSERT` statement: 1) if you don't specify `schema_name.table_name` then it's going to fallback to just using `table_name` in the database user's [`default_schema` setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql#b-changing-the-default-schema-of-a-user); and 2) the `BULK INSERT` statement is executed on the SQL Server instance itself, so any file path you have in `csv_buffer` must be visible to the SQL Server instance and accessible by the account under which it executes, i.e.: is it one of SQL Server's own drives or a file share?